# How to make these waves effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, shapes, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

[image]

I would like to to create the image above. I have tried to make multiples layers of the waves and edit it's opacity but it does not seem to work. I would really appreciate some feedback and guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you did? It seems that multiple layers of waves with opacity would be the answer, so it would be helpful to see where you're running into trouble.

Comment: what software are you using? you added a lot of tags to the question

Comment: Hi Floyd, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please tell us a bit more? What software do you want to achieve this in, and what do you have up till now that doesn't satisfy you? Please show us a screenshot of your work thus far. Thanks! If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

What I did:

- Create each wave with white to transparent gradient in different layers (maybe solid fill works better)
- Each layer is set as "Soft Light"
- Layer order does matter, play around which ones should go on top of which till you get the effect desired.
- Set varying opacity for the lighter ones

I did it in all of 10 minutes I think. Hope it gives you an idea as to how to achieve it.

Comment: did you use photoshop?

Comment: Photoshop CS6 yes.